# Microstrategy Output Level Error

Tags: sql, cross-join, microstrategy

I am doing my training in MicroStrategy and I was practicing creating filters with Output Levels with 3 attributes: Country, Product and Year, and one Metric Sum OrderQuantity from FactResellerSales with the metric as a report filter, with output levels on the product and year attributes only and not aggregated on country.

However, I am getting completely different set of numbers than what's given in the book and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I can see that remove the country attribute from the report altogether gives accurate data set as far as what's shown in the book. 
Below is what I saw in SQL view. Please help me understand what could be going wrong in this report.

```
select  a11.ProductKey  ProductKey,
    a12.CalendarYear  CalendarYear
into ##T3X3AC0ARMQ000
from    FactResellerSales   a11
    join    DimDate a12
      on    (a11.OrderDateKey = a12.DateKey)
group by    a11.ProductKey,
    a12.CalendarYear
having  sum(a11.OrderQuantity) > 1000.0 

Pass1 -     Query Execution:    0:00:21.04
    Data Fetching and Processing:   0:00:00.00
      Data Transfer from Datasource(s): 0:00:00.00
    Other Processing:   0:00:00.03
    Rows selected: 210


select  a11.ProductKey  ProductKey,
    max(a15.EnglishProductName)  EnglishProductName,
    a12.CountryRegionCode  CountryRegionCode,
    max(a12.EnglishCountryRegionName)  EnglishCountryRegionName,
    a13.CalendarYear  CalendarYear,
    sum(a11.OrderQuantity)  WJXBFS1
from    FactResellerSales   a11
    cross join  DimGeography    a12
    join    DimDate a13
      on    (a11.OrderDateKey = a13.DateKey)
    join    ##T3X3AC0ARMQ000    pa14
      on    (a11.ProductKey = pa14.ProductKey and 
    a13.CalendarYear = pa14.CalendarYear)
    join    DimProduct  a15
      on    (a11.ProductKey = a15.ProductKey)
group by    a11.ProductKey,
    a12.CountryRegionCode,
    a13.CalendarYear

Pass2 -     Query Execution:    0:00:00.00
    Data Fetching and Processing:   0:00:00.00
      Data Transfer from Datasource(s): 0:00:00.00
    Other Processing:   0:00:00.00
[Populate Report Data]

Pass3 -     Query Execution:    0:00:00.00
    Data Fetching and Processing:   0:00:00.00
      Data Transfer from Datasource(s): 0:00:00.00
    Other Processing:   0:00:00.02

drop table ##T3X3AC0ARMQ000
```

Answer (score 1):

Of couse you are having strange data when you put the country attribut in: this crete a cross join with the Geography.
I cannot know preisely why because i do not know the schema of your data mart but i'd say that it look like that DimGeography is not in your fact table; at least not directly.
Is common to create a duplicate hierarchy so you might have SalesGeography.

If you give me more details I can help you more.